# Why is IntlDateFormatter not found?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

The php-intl extension is loaded
since I can use  IntlDateFormatter::SHORT in a view script with no issue.

bit in my ViewHelper

```
<?php

namespace Common\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class DateFormat extends AbstractHelper {

    public function __invoke($dateField) {
        $dateFormatter=$this->getView()->plugin('dateformat');        
        return $dateFormatter(strtotime($dateField),       IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);  
    }
}
?>
```

I get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'Common\View\Helper\IntlDateFormatter' not found in
>   C:\TEMP\zf2ad\client\module\Common\src\Common\View\Helper\DateFormat.php
>   on line 12

Please advise

Ephraim

Answer (score 3):

Since you're working in a namespace context, it looks for the class in the actual namespace `Common\View\Helper`. You have to add a backslash in front of a class if it's in the global namespace.

```
return $dateFormatter(strtotime($dateField), \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
```